# simple c++ code not working in visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Terraria Part 3: The Return of the Guide");
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    (
        cout << "cannot find window." << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(-1);
    )

        return 0;
}
```

I wrote
this exactly like the video I was watching told me too and it gave me a Microsoft visual studio error code but it works if I take out
(
cout << "cannot find window." << endl;
Sleep(3000);
exit(-1);
)

Comment: *"it gave me a Microsoft visual studio error code"* - which you mysteriously decided wasn't worth putting in your post? **Always** include verbatim error messaging when your problem involves errors. We're not mind readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **if statement** has bad syntax. Change the if statement from..

```
if (hwnd == NULL)
    (
        cout << "cannot find window." << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(-1);
    )
```

to...

```
if (hwnd == NULL)
    { // <-- specifically these
        cout << "cannot find window." << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(-1);
    } // <--
```